# Is "for perpetuity" a synonym of "permanently"?

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms, phrase-usage

I am looking for another way to say *permanently* ("not temporarily"), like in:

> Starting from today, the rule 'A' will hold _______.

and was wondering if *for perpetuity* is a grammatically correct phrase to use here? The sense, which I would like to imply, is that something is no longer temporary (and not so much that it is going to stay / be present *forever*).

Remark: I know that *permanently* fits well in the particular sentence, however, I need to use the adverb more than a few times in my text, so would like to use a synonym once in a while.

Comment: You'll occasionally find *for perpetuity* meaning forever.  The more usual phrasing is *in perpetuity*.  I'm not sure what it means to have a permanent rule that doesn't last indefinitely.

Comment: I'm not sure how 'permanently' is guaranteeable, given that the sun has a finite life.

Comment: The delay in close-vote reason appearance strikes again. //  A quick search for << "for perpetuity" meaning >> immediately turns up the ODO (I believe) definition of the phrase. And [RHK Webster's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/perpetuity) adds the usual pragmatic 'for the foreseeable future' sense: 2. endless or indefinitely long duration or existence.

Comment: It means "To Infinity and Beyond!"

Comment: (But "in perpetuity" is the more common usage.)

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question regarding Perpetuity, but I would advise against filling the blank given that you do not wish to say  "so much as it is going to stay forever" in this sentence. That is because "hold" may be used as an intransitive verb that indicates that something will last all by itself, making it unnecessary to add the words, unless you want to specify the exact duration. "[Hold](http://www.tfd.com/hold) V. Intr. 2. a. To maintain a desired or accustomed position or condition: hopes the weather will hold." – The American Heritage Dictionary, 5th edition.

Answer (score 0):

I  think you could say:

"Starting from today, the rule 'A' will be effective".

***[effective](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/effective)***:

> - actually in operation or in force; functioning:
>
>   - *The law becomes effective at midnight.*

- that would imlpy that the rule will be valid until further notice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "for perpetuity" is grammatical.  However, "in perpetuity," using the preposition "in" beforehand rather than "for," is the far more common way of saying it.  See the Google Ngram below for a breakdown:

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+perpetuity%2C+for+perpetuity&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20perpetuity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20perpetuity%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0):

For those of us in the business of preserving objects for very long periods of time in a human sense (e.g., centuries), we commonly use the phrases "in perpetuity" or "for perpetuity" (the latter less commonly). Although this may be permanent in the sense of a single human lifespan, we recognize that in geological time permanence is much less likely and that in galactic time the chances of achieving our goals of object preservation are virtually nil. So we rarely use *permanent* or *forever* to describe the time sense of our goals. Thus, in answer to your titular question, in most human endeavors the answer should be "no," and in the context of human rules, given the pace of cultural evolution, terms like *henceforth* and *effective immediately* would probably be more appropriate.